# Oracle BI Start up fails to start Admin Server

Tags: oracle, weblogic, obiee

I'm trying to startup OBIEE 12c
Database is up and running

But running the start.cmd fails when starting Admin Server with this error message.

"""""
Starting AdminServer ...
Unable to connect to AdminServer on host: ***********

Failed to start one or more Servers

/Servers/AdminServer/ListenPort=9500
Accessing admin server using URL t3://*************
Start Admin Server connect Exception caught Error occurred while performing connect : Error getting the initial context. There is no server running at t3://************* : Failed to initialize JNDI context, tried 2 time or times totally, the interval of each time is 0ms.
t3://*************: Destination **********, 9500 unreachable.; nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; No available router to destination.; nested exception is:
java.rmi.ConnectException: No available router to destination.
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace :
Reading domain...
Error: runCmd() failed. Do dumpStack() to see details.
Failed to get Status of Servers and System Components
"""""

[Start.cmd error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Bf0.png)

Also, trying to check the status come up with this error.

"""""
Start Admin Server connect Exception caught Error occurred while performing connect : Error getting the initial context. There is no server running at t3://************* : Failed to initialize JNDI context, tried 2 time or times totally, the interval of each time is 0ms.
t3://*************: Destination 10.10.3.88, 9500 unreachable.; nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; No available router to destination.; nested exception is:
java.rmi.ConnectException: No available router to destination.
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace :
Reading domain...
Error: runCmd() failed. Do dumpStack() to see details.
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
File "F:\Middleware\bi\modules\oracle.bi.sysman\scripts\status_servers.py", line 29, in ?
File "F:\Middleware\bi\modules\oracle.bi.sysman\scripts\process_control.py", line 581, in statusComponents
File "F:\Middleware\bi\modules\oracle.bi.sysman\scripts\process_control.py", line 455, in outputComponentsStatus
File "F:\Middleware\bi\modules\oracle.bi.sysman\scripts\process_control.py", line 243, in connectAdminServer
File "F:\Middleware\bi\modules\oracle.bi.sysman\scripts\process_control.py", line 179, in requestCredentialsAndConnectToAdminServer
File "F:\Middleware\bi\modules\oracle.bi.sysman\scripts\process_control.py", line 513, in getAdminServerUrl
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\WLSTOfflineIni5666259588766029647.py", line 131, in readDomain
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\WLSTOfflineIni5666259588766029647.py", line 19, in command
60713: Attempt to execute command "readDomain" in invalid state: Configuration
"""""
[STATUS ERROR MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lReKG.png)

Comment: Check the actual server logs.   $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/logs
There is more than likely the actual problem documented in there